# "This is considered..." vs. "This is considered as..."

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Does this "as" change the meaning or correctness of this sentence?

> This is considered **as** socially desired.
>   This is considered socially desired.

Are both of them grammatically correct? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think *as* changes the meaning or is wrong, but to me it sounds better to leave it out. There's a good discussion of this question here: http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/consider-and-consider-as

> Editor Emily Brewster responds:
>
> > In all four cases, the sentences without *as* are more idiomatic. However, as the article at *consider* in *Merriam-Webster's Concise Dictionary of English Usage* states, "as constructions are perfectly idiomatic but are not as common in recent use as they have been in the past. Nonetheless, they are still in use and are standard."